# Can you get systemd-networkd to accept an IPv6 RA *route* but not auto-assign an *address*?

Tags: debian, ipv6, systemd-networkd

I've got a network with both an `radvd` and a `kea-dhcp6` server running. Clients are running `systemd-networkd` (currently debian stable) and:

```
[Network]
IPv6AcceptRA=true
DHCP=yes
```

The desired behaviour is to get the client configured with an address from DHCPv6, and also a route from RA. Currently, with this configuration, the client gets the correct IP address from DHCP, an auto-generated / auto-assigned `global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute` address, and the correct route

```
default proto static metric 1024
        nexthop via fe80::20d:b9ff:fe54:2d18 dev eno1 weight 1 pref medium
```

For boring reasons, I'd like the system to prefer the DHCPv6-assigned address as a source address. From what I can tell, it's possible to do this either by setting this address as the "home" address, or by making it the only address available. I gather that `systemd-networkd` can't set the `home` flag currently on a DHCP-obtained address, so I was trying to work out how to do the latter.

The problem is that by setting `IPv6AcceptRA=false`, this does indeed remove the address, but it also removes the default LL-address route, which breaks a bunch of other things.

Is there a way I can have the RA-assigned LL route, but not have the auto-configured address that comes with it?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution depends on whether you want to disable address auto-configuration for the whole network, or just for one device.

For the whole network you can tell `radvd` to not set the "autonomous" flag in its announcements. That will prevent all systems on the network from autogenerating their own addresses. You can use the `AdvAutonomous` option for that.

If you want to set this on the client at the kernel level, you need to tell the kernel to not generate its own addresses. This is easiest done by creating `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-autoconf.conf` with these contents:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
```

This file is processed after each reboot. You can activate the new settings manually by runnint `sudo sysctl --system`.

When you want to use `systemd-networkd` the following should work, but I haven't tried it myself:

```
[Network]
IPv6AcceptRA=true
DHCP=yes

[IPv6AcceptRA]
UseAutonomousPrefix=false
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I have some Android devices on this network, so disabling `AdvAutonomous` is not an option. I will experiment with the systctl settings.

Comment: Alas, despite setting `net.ipv6.conf.[all|default|eth0].autoconf=0`, I still get a `dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute` address on startup, and when restarting `networkd`